# How do I reformat the output of a BASH script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to find specific files in a directory that contain a string.

Code I've written so far:

```
for x in $(find "$1" -type f -name "*."$2"") ;
do  
     grep -Hrnw $x -e "$3"
done
```

The output I get:

```
./crop.py:2:import torch
./crop.py:3:import torch.backends.cudnn as cudnn
```

I am trying to get spaces on both sides of the colon like this:

```
./crop.py : 2 : import torch
./crop.py : 3 : import torch.backends.cudnn as cudnn
```

I am fairly new to programing in BASH. I've tried using `sed` command but had not luck with it.

Comment: `... done | sed -e 's/:/ : /g`

Comment: Note that `for x in $(find ...)` runs afoul of [BashPitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) and [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor); it has lots of subtle bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find "$1" -type f -name "*.$2" | xargs grep -Hrnw -e "$3"| sed 's/:/ : /g'
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to get spaces on both sides of the colon

> I've tried using sed command but had not luck with it.

```
sed 's/:/ : /g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a `for`-loop for browsing through the `find` results, while you can use a `find ... -exec`?

Like this:

```
find "$1" -type f -name "*."$2"" -exec grep -Hrnw {} -e "$3" \;
```

(I didn't test this, it might contain some bugs)

Comment: Don't you mean `-name "*.$2"`? `$2` should not be unquoted -- having it outside of quotes means the results of that expansion are subject to word-splitting and globbing.

Comment: The other thing I would strongly suggest is making it `-exec grep -Hrnw -e "$3" {} +` -- much more efficient when you pass as many files as possible to each instance of `grep` as `-exec ... {} +` does, instead of calling `grep` once per file, as `-exec ... {} ... \;` does. And I don't think this covers the adding-spaces-around-the-colons part of the OP's goal, unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to try one liner command:

```
grep -Hrnw "$3" $(find "$1" -type f -name "*.$2" -printf "\"%p\"\n") | sed 's/:/ : /g'
```